# Visual basic - my string comparison function not working correctly

Tags: vb.net

I have data like: (id,volume,median.percantile)

```
1  Normal Normal Low
2  Low Normal High
3  High High Normal
```

What I need to do is to have a counter that it increases by 1 when it is not Normal. So I expect

```
1  Normal Normal Low Counter:1
2  Low Normal High Counter:2
3  High High Low Counter:3
```

To provide it I wrote the function below. However, when I send there (Normal,Normal,High), it is calculating it 2 instead 1. So it is not working correctly. Where is my mistake?

My code is below:

```
Public Function getPoint(ByVal volume As String, ByVal median As String, ByVal percantile As String) As Integer

  Dim Total As Integer = 0
  If volume = “Normal” then 
    total = total + 1 
  end if
  If median = “Normal” then 
    total = total + 1
  end if
  If percantile = “Normal” then 
    total = total + 1 
  end if

  return total

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is opposite to what you want.

You want the count of not-Normal whereas what you are counting and returning the total is Normal.

Simple fix would be `return (3 - total)`.

Btw, is this VBA or VB.Net? Both are based on VB but are different.
If it's VBA for Excel, you can achieve this using simple count formula (3 - count of Normal).

Answer (score 1):

In the first record, both `volume` *and* `median` are `"Normal"`.  So *both* of these conditions are true:

```
If volume = "Normal" Then 
  total = total + 1 
End If
If median = "Normal" Then 
  total = total + 1
End If
```

Thus, `total` gets incremented twice.  If you want it to be incremented only once (and essentially ignore the remaining comparisons) then use `ElseIf` to stop the comparisons once a condition has been satisfied:

```
If volume = "Normal" Then 
  total = total + 1 
ElseIf median = "Normal" Then 
  total = total + 1
End If
```

Or just put them into a single condition:

```
If volume = "Normal" Or median = "Normal" Then
  total = total + 1
End If
```

---

Note that this behavior is exactly the opposite of what you describe:

> increases by 1 when it is not Normal

A typo perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `"="`'s to `"<>"`
i.e.

```
If volume <> "Normal" then 
    total = total + 1 
End if
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct, but it would be helpful to provide some context to the problem instead of just the correct code. Read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)